# Database Change Notifications using ENABLE_BROKER

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, signalr

I want "Database Change Notifications in ASP.NET using SignalR and SqlDependency"
using "ENABLE_BROKER" in SQL Server. Is it wise decision than using trigger or it may cause slowness of database please share your knowledge it would be greatful.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I am trying to do in this way.
http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency

Comment: Can you explain `cause slowness of database`. Everything you do affects performance.